# Div's stack on top of each other, just not in right order

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a couple divs, placed side by side and using a media query to stack them, which they do stack but I need the yellow one to be on top and the blue below it. So opposite of what you see when the script is ran and not sure on how to do it.

```css
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
}
#mydivLeft {
    background:blue;
    height:250px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

#mydivRight {
    background:yellow;
    height:250px;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    #wrapper {
        width:100%;
    }

    #mydivRight, #mydivLeft {
        display:block;
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    }

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="mydivLeft">
        </div>
        <div id="mydivRight">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just reverse the order of the divs in the HTML to be whatever order you want them to be.

```css
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
}
#mydivLeft {
    background:blue;
    height:250px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

#mydivRight {
    background:yellow;
    height:250px;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    #wrapper {
        width:100%;
    }

    #mydivRight, #mydivLeft {
        display:block;
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    }

}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="mydivRight">
  </div>
  <div id="mydivLeft">
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, a more complicated solution is to use flexbox, and use the `order` property or `flex-direction: column-reverse;` to re-order the flex children.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
}

#wrapper > div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
}

#mydivLeft {
  background: blue;
}

#mydivRight {
  background: yellow;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    width: auto;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  #wrapper > div {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="mydivLeft">
  </div>
  <div id="mydivRight">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works fine, however in production it doesnt seem to want to work properly because I still have the left side going to the top and the left to the bottom

Comment: @Chris weird, not sure why... this is insanely simple. For what it's worth, I updated my answer and added a flexbox solution. Flexbox lets you re-order the order of elements via CSS, which is pretty cool. Maybe that will help?

Comment: I found some css in another file and it looks like this ( I changed the div names to match the ones I have here ) #mydivLeft, #mydivRight
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 0 80px;
}
and thats being called first and not sure is would be blocking it or not?

Comment: @Chris could be. If you inspect element, you should see which rule is taking taking effect and which ones are being overwritten.

Comment: I did what you suggested and when the media query kicks in then the code I showed you from the other css file, the float:left and width:50% are crossed out

Comment: If it still isn't working, maybe you can provide a screenshot of what you're seeing? Like a screenshot of the page, the HTML elements, and the CSS in the dev tools?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133731/discussion-between-chris-and-michael-coker).

Answer (score 2):

you can use `flexbox` using `order` to reverse the order of how the elements are stacked

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 250px;
}
#wrapper div {
  flex: 1;
}
#mydivLeft {
  background: blue;
}
#mydivRight {
  background: yellow;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #wrapper div {
    flex: 0 100%
  }
  #mydivRight {
    order: -1
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mydivLeft">
    </div>
    <div id="mydivRight">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can't just change the color because each div has elements in them. This is a test run before I run it live

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox layout. By default the `flex-direction` is `row`, in the media queries change it to `column-reverse`.

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
}
#mydivLeft, #mydivRight {
  flex: 1;
  height: 250px;
}
#mydivLeft {
  background: blue;
}
#mydivRight {
  background: yellow;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #wrapper {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="mydivLeft"></div>
  <div id="mydivRight"></div>
</div>
```